# jquery mobile & php

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

When I pressed submit, but its value should not try to go over to php.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">              
</script>    
<Link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

But like change under the order of the above source , this value is passed to php.

```
<Link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<Script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
```

However, the framework is broken jquery mobile.
How did the values ​​passed without breaking ?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8" content="text/html>`enter code here`

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/spinbox/latest/jqm-spinbox.min.js"></script>
</script>
</head> 
<body>
        <div  data-role="page">
            <h1 id="header">IT Cafe</h1>
            <a href="#hot" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" id="homeicon" ></a>
            <a href="#shop" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="shop" data-iconpos="notext" id="shopicon" ></a>
            <nav data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#hot" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" >Coffee(Hot)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ice" >Coffee(Ice)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="e#tc" >Etc</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
                        <form name="f" method="post" action="submit.php"> 
<input type="text" name="test" /> 
<input type="submit" value="submit" /> 
</form> 
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

submit.php

```
<?php 
    echo "<pre>"; 
    print_r($_POST); 
    echo "</pre>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Please take care to format your code so that it's at least somewhat readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, fixed it:

PAGE 1: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/spinbox/latest/jqm-spinbox.min.js"></script>

</head> 
<body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <h1 id="header">IT Cafe</h1>
            <a href="#hot" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" id="homeicon" ></a>
            <a href="#shop" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="shop" data-iconpos="notext" id="shopicon" ></a>
            <nav data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#hot" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" >Coffee(Hot)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ice" >Coffee(Ice)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="e#tc" >Etc</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <form name="f" method="post" action="submit.php"> 
                <input type="text" name="test" /> 
                <input type="submit" value="submit" /> 
            </form> 
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PAGE 2: submit.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery MOBILE</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>Page 2</h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            You Selected:  
            <?php 
                $var = $_POST['test'];
                if(isset($var)){echo $var;}     
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not same. first  Jquery mobile css, second jquery, third jquery mobile library. if jquery mobile library

Comment: ^ Check that out. You need to style the output page in jQuery Mobile format like I did above.

Comment: To retract a value in the list and select box of jquery mobile do you write the php within the framework ?

Comment: You can do that as per how you want to implement, but I'd personally just write my own php handlers and separate ajax for submits. Please upvote if the answer helped.